# New Relic Monitoring for Play framework 2.0.4 and 2.1

Tags: playframework-2.0, newrelic

I try to search a monitoring tool for my app built on Play 2.X. However, most of the answers I found point to this thread.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/AE1INL1iqrs

Also another SO comment mentions New Relic currently not support Play 2.X.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12735426/772481

New Relic documentation only mentions Play 1.2.4.

https://newrelic.com/docs/java/new-relic-for-java

Is there any workaround for New Relic on Play 2.X?

Comment: This blog post suggests it'l work for Play 2: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/blog/2012/09/03/install-new-relic-addon-for-play-2-framework-on-heroku/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using New Relic with Play 2.1/Scala 2.10. Play/Scala/Netty support has been introduced in New Relic 2.19.0. There were some stability problems in this version (memory consumption, performance issue during instrumentation). Those issues have been fixed in the meanwhile (New Relic Agent 2.20).

See our blog post about how to setup.
http://techblog.nezasa.com/2013/08/performance-monitoring-of-nezasa-with.html

Answer (score 3):

New relic has just updated  their java agent to work with Netty server and play 2 framework: 
https://newrelic.com/docs/java/new-relic-for-java

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there's currently a good way to get New Relic stats from a Play 2.x application.