# Play 2.1 / taking in account a javaagent while running tests

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, aspectj, playframework-2.1, javaagents

My goal is to launch my integration tests contained within my **Play** app.

To do so, I used to launch them through Intellij.
Those tests needs Spring aspectJ weaving, thus I precised in my Intellij test conf this VM argument:

```
-javaagent:/Users/myName/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-instrument/jars/spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

The whole works.

Now I want to be able to launch them through command-line using the simple `play` command following by `test-only` command.

First I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012562/is-it-possible-to-run-play-framework-2-0-server-with-a-javaagent) post dealing with the way to add any javaagent to Play app.

Thus, I modify my Play's `build` file like this, adding the Spring's javaagent:

```
java ${DEBUG_PARAM} -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M ${JAVA_OPTS} -javaagent:/Users/myName/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-instrument/jars/spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dplay.version="${PLAY_VERSION}" -Dsbt.ivy.home=`dirname $0`/../repository -Dplay.home=`dirname $0` -Dsbt.boot.properties=`dirname $0`/sbt/sbt.boot.properties -jar `dirname $0`/sbt/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

However, my test merely fails.. complaining about the missing Spring's aspectJ weaving.
But it's surely logic since `test-only` launches another process...

Is there a way to make my test care about aspectJ weaving using javaagent?

Comment: Take a look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201034/how-to-debug-tests-with-play-2-0/15920921#15920921

Comment: @Igor Romanov Awesome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the link provided by @Igor Romanov in the above comment, here my solution:

```
val myApp = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    Keys.javaOptions in (Test) +=
     "-javaagent:/Users/myName/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework/spring-instrument/jars/spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar",
    // code remaining
```

This allows to apply **load-time weaving** for class dealing with Spring's aspectj.

The whole works pretty well :)   (tested with SBT 0.12.3, Scala 2.10 and Play 2.1)